# Why can't I access newly added elements (modal popup) in Javascript, even in the developer console?

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce-lightning

I'm probably missing something obvious here but I'm pretty experienced with html and javascript and this is throwing me. I'm writing a browser plugin for Salesforce Lightning users. I want to get access to the form fields in the New Contact screen. My script wasn't working and when I drilled down I found the issue and I can reproduce it just in the dev tools:

I log into Salesforce, click Contact, then New. A New Contact window pops up.

I right click on a form field (e.g. phone number input) and click Inspect. I can see the ID of the element, e.g. "input-169"

```html
<input type="text" id="input-169" maxlength="40" name="MobilePhone" class="slds-input">
```

I go to the console and type in

```js
document.getElementById('input-169');
```

The return value is null.

If I do this for an element that was already there before the New Contact popup window, it works fine.

If I try other ways to find the element, for example document.getElementsByTagName(), it does not show up that way either, but other elements that were there before the popup window all work.

If I add my own element next to the one I want (i.e. at the same DOM level) by editing the html, I can access that new element successfully, but still not access the one that was added by the popup window.

I can reproduce this in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.

What's going on and is there any way to tell the browser to notice the elements in the popup window?

Comment: Most likely your Javascript code is running before the element is rendered and registered in the DOM.

Comment: @nadz I'm not sure you read the question. I'm working in the developer console after the content is completely rendered.

Comment: You could use JQuery selector $("#input-169") to target the input fields. I tested it works. But for some reason the Javascript queryselector cannot find the element.

Comment: @nadz interesting thanks. How did you load jQuery to test this? I can't get jquery to load.

Comment: You can use the following code to include Jquery.
`var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: @nadz I tried that (and something similar) and got the following error. Did you mean to say you got this working on a Salesforce Lightning page? --> Refused to load the script 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-QEz6xTG4dKodIrZ3jVXLkRacCUgKcQfF' chrome-extension: 'unsafe-eval' *.canary.lwc.dev *.na138.visual.force.com......

Comment: Sorry, I tried the Salesforce classic. I'll try with the Lightning interface as well.

Comment: @nadz thank you! This really has me stumped. It seems like certain elements beyond a certain place in the DOM just can't be accessed and I can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce.com Lightning interface is using [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) and the [Shadow Dom](https://javascript.info/shadow-dom) to build its UI. To access the invisible elements you need to use the [shadowRoot property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) of the custom elements.